# CAShapeLayer is sometimes visible but sometime is not

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cashapelayer

Inside UICollectionViewCell I add `CAShapeLayer circle` inside initWithCoder;

So here I didn't do anything unusual, its very simple. But when I launch the app, the circle is sometimes visible, but sometimes is not.

I logged the circle where I saw that the color, opacity, path and frame is set properly. But on the screen there's no circle. If I begin scrolling collection view, the circle appears right away. Also if I touch any other button or scroll on the screen. I even try to make a screenshot for you to see it, but at the moment I take a screenshot, the circle appears right away. So I can't show the problem to you.

I thing it's possible that this is a mistake made inside the iOS. Is there a way to force to redraw the circle.

here is my initializor

```
- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
  self = [super initWithCoder:coder];
  if (self) {
    CAShapeLayer *circle = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    circle.contentsScale = SCREEN_SCALE;
    circle.rasterizationScale = 2.0 * SCREEN_SCALE;
    circle.shouldRasterize = YES;
    circle.opacity = 1.0;
    circle.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
    circle.fillColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50);
    circle.frame = frame;
    circle.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:frame].CGPath;

    [self.layer addSublayer:circle];
  }
  return self;
}
```

I think I didnt do anything wrong, there didnt do anything else with the circle elsewhere in the code.

Comment: Try adding [circle setNeedsDisplay]

Comment: Doesn't work. The problem still exist.